# Create list of lists based on a condition

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a string like below:

```
result = """The following table provides the details.
acquired, by major class:
(US$ in millions)    Customer relationships       15year       $265
There is another line without space here.
Another table starts here:
(USS in millions)       2018       2017
Income (loss) from continuing operations       $298       $129"""
```

I have to take all the sentences that contain more than 3 spaces and put them in a list of lists. Below is something I have tried so far:

```
lines = result.splitlines()
table_list = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if re.search(r'   {3,}', lines[i]):
        table_list.append(lines[i])
```

**Resultant output of above code:**

```
['(US$ in millions)       Customer relationships      15year      $265','(USS in millions)     2018      2017','Income (loss) from continuing operations       $298      $129']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[['(US$ in millions)       Customer relationships      15year      $265'],['(USS in millions)       2018       2017','Income (loss) from continuing operations       $298       $129']]
```

**Further explanation of output condition:** Expected output should be a **list of lists**. While iterating through each line, if there are consecutive sentences that contain 3 or more spaces between 2 words, all of these lines should be part of same list within the main list. If a line does not contain 3 or more spaces between 2 words, this breaks the chain. If there is another line that contains 3 or more spaces between 2 words then this line becomes part of a new list inside the main list.

Comment: Resultant output is not list of list. Expected output has list of list. I am facing problem in creating list of list with the condition.

Comment: your expected output has two strings in the second nested list. is that intentional? what's the logic behind that?

Comment: Please do not give negative rating to the question. If there is more information required, then I am happy to share.

Comment: @Najeem yes, that is expected because those 2 strings are 2 consecutive strings which contains 3 or more spaces between 2 words.

Comment: I think it will help if you replace \s and \n with actual spaces and newline characters. scrolling sideways isnt easy and also your text cannot be used to test a solution. Also, what do you mean by sentences. There are no full stops in your entire text.

Comment: I have reformatted the example text. Thanks @mkrieger1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` with `re.findall`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def has_spaces(str_):
    return bool(re.findall("\s{3,}", str_))

[list(g) for k, g in groupby(result.splitlines(), key=has_spaces) if k]
```

Output:

```
[['(US$ in millions)    Customer relationships       15year       $265'],
 ['(USS in millions)       2018       2017',
  'Income (loss) from continuing operations       $298       $129']]
```